# Citation in plain text

Tags: beamer, citing

I need to cite a paper at the end of a quotation right after the end of the text in beamer. In my example the reference appears after the text, *but* in italics. How can I change it to the normal font?

[image]

Comment: Without a complete minimal working example it's difficult to help. You show us a cake and we must guess the increments.

Comment: sure sorry ill post it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `quote` environment with a `\cite` you can insert `\upshape` just before the citation, which switches to an upright font (rather than italic).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{quote}
    ``quotation''\cite{author}
  \end{quote} 
  \begin{quote}
    ``quotation''\upshape\cite{author}
  \end{quote} 
Citation outside quote: \cite{author}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{author}
Something written by someone.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]